# Is type hinting make script execution faster inPHP8+

Tags: performance, type-hinting, php-8

Does type hinting type parameters in function and return types (mixed return etc..)

Make the code execution faster ?

I mean i love it for defensive coding, extrem programming but is this really impacting performances : low or high ?

I made some tests but this is contradictive on huge servers with big iterations with & without extensions with PHP8/FPM.

I want to say also that i obviously know that this is slighty costless comparative to the beauty/defensiveness/scalableness  of the code.

Thanks

Comment: They can allow more optimization if Opcache is enabled but in practice it's rare. Watch this video for more explanation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JBWgvUrb-q8&t=1628s

Answer (score 1):

Look at it logically: the engine needs an additional check in order to verify the function's output, thus it has to take longer. Keep in mind that PHP is not a statically compiled language (like Java) so the return type is verified during the runtime.

Without output type hint it's one opcode less
https://3v4l.org/cnOb8/vld#output

With output type hint it's one opcode more
https://3v4l.org/ZuRAY/vld#output

The benefit far outweights the cost though. Are you sure you're not [prematurely optimizing](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/) your code?

Comment: Sure but C does not have to "cast" variables if this is typed so this is not very obvious for me..

Comment: PHP is not C, sorry ;)

Comment: Not at all, the costs are useless i know.

Comment: You're mixing two different aspects here. For instance, you could have a PHP compiler written in NodeJS. PHP is PHP and is not related to C in any way.

Comment: Okay so i'm talking about the JIT compilation in PHP8+, in PHP7+ this is slower, i ran some tests with huges iterations/servers/extensions and this in not obvious. I asked this to a known PHP contributer. Can we talk in a private way to show you my tests ?

Comment: JIT compiles the code, the output still has to be validated during the runtime against the expected return type.

Comment: Okay, but scripts can be opcached if you setup properly headers & http server and those are not interpreted but completly compiled ! SO ?